# Padding for Hex to Binary Conversion so each hex digit produces 4 bits

Tags: java, string, binary, hex, data-conversion

I have the following code that attempts to left-pad a binary string with zeroes:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(input, 16);
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
String pad = String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0');
```

When the input is `"1"`, it correctly produces `"0001"`, but if I add an extra hex digits, it doesn't add anymore padding. For example, `"2F"` produces `"101111"`, but I want it to be 8 bits like `001011111`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: But `2F` in binary has 6 bits (`101111`). What do you mean you only want 4 bits?.You can't write it with only 4 bits - there is no padding involved here. Please clarify what the actual problem is.

Comment: I mean I want each Hex value to have 4 bits long, so if since 2 is 0010, I want those other 0 in the front

Comment: Thank you for fixing my question Bohemian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've specified a *minimum* width of `4`, but `2F` has *6* bits, so 6 characters are produced.

You can either:

- Format each single hex digit individually and concatenate the results
- Make the format width dynamic - 4 times the number of hex digits
- Use a string-based approach
- Something else

The simplest is a string-based approach, if you rephrase your requirement to "always produce a multiple of 4 bits".

Here's how you do that:

```
String pad = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0')
    .replaceAll("^(0000)+", "");
```

The difference is I changed the output to be `32` characters (the maximum bits an `int` can be) and trimmed off leading zeroes 4 at a time by adding `.replaceAll("^(0000)+", "")` to your code.

That regex matches "1 or more occurrences of `0000` at the start of the string" and the replacement term is a blank, so anything matched is "deleted".

Comment: Isn't it simpler to use `String.format("%032s", ...).replaceAll(...)?`
Does String.format not understand "%0"?

Comment: @bipll I thought of that, but when I checked the doc I found the `0` padding flag is only available for numeric types :(

Comment: Aha. Then maybe it is preferable to change the way of replacement: `.replaceAll("^(    )+", "").replace(' ', '0')`, this way we avoid unnecessary space-to-zero conversions.

Comment: And zero itself should be handled specially to not turn into an empty string.